# 302 Redirect prevents callback in Request

Tags: node.js

I've noticed some websites don't close 302 redirects which causes the callback not to fire.

Anyone know how to remedy this?

```
var request = require('request');

request({url:'http://craigslist.org' }, function (error, response, body)
{
    console.log("Callback Never Runs. ");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, upon further investigation this suggestion also fails. But when trying multiple times with your code that will work occasionally too. The best I've come up with is using a timeout to retry. timeout fires the complete event where you can check if the request really finished and if not retry.

```
var request = require('request');

function doRequest(location) {
    request({
      timeout: 5000, // five seconds
      url:location
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        console.log("Callback Never Runs. ");
    }).on("complete", function(response) {
      if(!response.complete) setImmediate(function() {
         doRequest(location);
      });
    });
}

doRequest('http://craigslist.org');
```

You can expand on this further to only retry X number of times before throwing an error.

----original----

This could be a bug in request as in this case craigslist.org sends all 302 errors. But if you add followAllRedirects: true to you options it works.

```
var request = require('request');

request({
  followAllRedirects: true,
  url:'http://craigslist.org'
}, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log("Callback Never Runs. ");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you include a `User-Agent` (such as [your browser's](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=user-agent)):

```
request({
    url: 'http://craigslist.com',
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (...) ...'
    }
}, function (err, res, body) {
    // ...
});
```

Without that, Craigslist seems to leave the connection open, so it doesn't `'end'` or `'complete'` and the `callback` isn't called.